# How to use bind with many tables in controller in cakephp 3.x?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

**I have three tables**

in Events table

```
id
event_name
patient_id
madical_case_id
fees
```

in madicalCases table

```
id
patient_id
case_type
date
```

in Patients table

```
id
name
address
```

now i try to find all Events with bind(madicalCases and Patients).
    but not getting succsess

---

```
**i try this**

$this->belongsTo('Patients', ['foreignKey' => 'patient_id', 'joinType' => 'INNER']);
$this->belongsTo('MadicalCases', ['foreignKey' => 'madical_case_id', 'joinType' => 'INNER']);
$event = $this->Events->find()->where(['patient_id' => $patient_id], ['madical_case_id' => $mc_id])->all();

            OR

$this->belongsTo('MadicalCases', ['foreignKey' => 'madical_case_id', 'joinType' => 'INNER','Patients', ['foreignKey' => 'patient_id', 'joinType' => 'INNER']]);
$event = $this->Events->find()->where(['patient_id' => $patient_id], ['madical_case_id' => $mc_id])->all();
```

**here some error**

```
Call to undefined method App\Controller\EventsController::belongsTo() in E:\wamp\www\Gurukrupa\src\Controller\EventsController.php on line 36

Unable to emit headers. Headers sent in file=E:\wamp\www\Gurukrupa\src\Controller\EventsController.php line=36 [CORE\src\Http\ResponseEmitter.php, line 48]

Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at E:\wamp\www\Gurukrupa\src\Controller\EventsController.php:36) [CORE\src\Http\ResponseEmitter.php, line 149]

Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at E:\wamp\www\Gurukrupa\src\Controller\EventsController.php:36) [CORE\src\Http\ResponseEmitter.php, line 181]
```

Comment: siimply you are putting the relationships inside the controller but they go in the Table object. I suggest you to read the chapter abut creating associations https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html

Comment: error like this  *Unable to emit headers.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this->paginate = ['contain' => ['Patients', 'MadicalCases']];

$events = $this->Events->find('all')->where(['Events.patient_id' => $patient_id])->where(['Events.madical_case_id' => $madical_case_id]);

$allevents = $this->paginate($events);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ohh man, you tried to break well design beauty of MVC framework. You can't bindModel or unbindModel in controller for CakePHP Version 3. They no longer support in V3. It must be done via Table object. Now, you tried to call `belongTo` in controller. Check detail [here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/orm-migration.html) and it can be done something like this.

```
class MadicalCasesTable extends Table{
    public function initialize(array $config){
    $this->belongsTo('Patients')
        ->setForeignKey('patient_id')
        ->setJoinType('INNER');
    }
}
```

Comment: $this->belongsTo('Patients', [
           'foreignKey' => 'patient_id',
           'joinType' => 'INNER'
       ]);

but not working

Comment: and accessible return in Patients array count 1...  now i have no idea how to set *recursive 2*

Comment: Not need to add recursive. Can be done via `contain` and something like `$this->Articles->find('all')->contain(['Authors']);`

Comment: Call to undefined method Cake\ORM\ResultSet::contain()

Comment: Where do you call this function ?

Comment: in event controller(index action) like this $events = $this->Events->find()->all()->contain(['Authors']);

Comment: You can't copy and paste exactly like that i mentioned. You have to done yourself based on your requirement. You don't have Authors table and you did wrongly call to `find('all')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173124/discussion-between-vishal-vaghasiya-and-d3ad-l0ck).

Comment: but yes one reason that i have no Authors table because here only AppController..